# JSON Decoding error pops up, dunno what else to try

Tags: ios, json, swift

guys, I would really appreciate some help with JSON decoding. I am trying get API from this link: http://newsapi.org/v2/top-headlines?apiKey=a16b15f863454928804e218705d0f019+&country=us
I might have made some really amateur mistakes. First time uploading a problem here. TY for help!

Here is my DataManager

```
protocol NewsManagerDelegate {
    func didUpdateNews(news: NewsModel)
}
import Foundation

struct NewsManager{
    
    
    var delegate: NewsManagerDelegate?
    
    let url = "https://newsapi.org/v2/top-headlines?apiKey=a16b15f863454928804e218705d0f019"
    
    
    func fetchNews(_ countryName: String){
        let newsUrlString = "\(url)+&country=\(countryName)"
        performRequest(newsUrlString)
    }
    
    func performRequest(_ urlString: String){
        if let url = URL(string: urlString){
            let session = URLSession(configuration: .default)
            let task = session.dataTask(with: url) { (data, response, error) in
                if error != nil {
                    print("networking error \(error!)")
                    return
                }
                
                if let safeData = data{
                    if let news = parseJSON(safeData){
                        delegate?.didUpdateNews(news: news)
                }
            }
            }
            task.resume()
        }
    }
    
    func parseJSON(_ newsData: Data) -> NewsModel?{
        do{
            let decodedData = try JSONDecoder().decode(NewsData.self, from: newsData)
            let sourceName = decodedData.articles[5].source.name
            let titleName = decodedData.articles[5].title
            let linkToImage = decodedData.articles[5].urlToImage
            let news = NewsModel(sourceName: sourceName, titleName: titleName, linkToImage: linkToImage ) 
            return news
        }catch{
            print(error)
            return nil
        }
        
    }
    
    
    
    
    
}
```

and my Data

```
import Foundation

struct NewsData: Codable {
    let totalResults: Int
    let articles: [Articles]

}

struct Articles: Codable{
    let author: String?
    let title: String
    let description: String
    let urlToImage: String
    let source: Source
    
}

struct Source: Codable{
    let name: String
}
```

I am receiving this error

```
valueNotFound(Swift.String, Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [CodingKeys(stringValue: "articles", intValue: nil), _JSONKey(stringValue: "Index 0", intValue: 0), CodingKeys(stringValue: "description", intValue: nil)], debugDescription: "Expected String value but found null instead.", underlyingError: nil))
```

I tried to make some of the constants optional but after that no info would show up at all.

Comment: You can go through the log error and try to read it , it tells you all the path to the key causing the problem

Comment: Since you do seem to get data, but have trouble parsing it you should try to reduce the scope. Print out the JSON data and whittle it down to a single article example that fails to parse. Post it as a string (most likely in """-quotes to make it easier to read) and provide the error message you get. That way people will have less problems spotting the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would just change the property name to `articleDescription` and make it optional. If you would like to parse the `publishedAt` date all you need is to set decoder `dateDecodingStrategy` property to `.iso8601`. Besides that you are not constructing your url correctly. You should always use `URLComponents` when composing your url and change your urls properties types from `String` to `URL`:

```
struct Root: Codable {
    let status: String
    let totalResults: Int
    let articles: [Article]
}
```

---

```
struct Article: Codable {
    let source: Source
    let author: String?
    let title: String
    let articleDescription: String?
    let url, urlToImage: URL
    let publishedAt: Date
    let content: String?
    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case source, author, title, articleDescription = "description", url, urlToImage, publishedAt, content
    }
}
```

---

```
struct Source: Codable {
    let id: String?
    let name: String
}
```

---

Playground testing:

```
func fetchNews(_ countryCode: String) {
    var urlComponents = URLComponents()
    urlComponents.scheme = "https"
    urlComponents.host = "newsapi.org"
    urlComponents.path = "/v2/top-headlines"
    urlComponents.queryItems = [.init(name: "apiKey", value: "a16b15f863454928804e218705d0f019"),
                                .init(name:"country", value: countryCode)]
    if let url = urlComponents.url {
        performRequest(url)
    }
}
func performRequest(_ url: URL) {
    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { data, response, error in
        guard let data = data else {
            print("networking error", error ?? "nil")
            return
        }
        do {
            let decoder = JSONDecoder()
            decoder.dateDecodingStrategy = .iso8601
            let root = try decoder.decode(Root.self, from: data)
            let articles = root.articles
            for article in articles {
                print("article:", article, terminator: "\n")
            }
        } catch {
            print(error)
        }

    }.resume()
}
fetchNews("us")
```

---

This will print:

> article: Article(source: __lldb_expr_111.Source(id: Optional("cnn"), name: "CNN"), author: Optional("Oliver Darcy, CNN Business"), title: "Tucker Carlson backlash tells us something important about some Trump supporters - CNN", articleDescription: nil, url: https://www.cnn.com/2020/11/21/media/tucker-carlson-fox-news-traitor/index.html, urlToImage: https://cdn.cnn.com/cnnnext/dam/assets/201105014450-tucker-carlson-fox-news-presidential-election-fraud-super-tease.jpg, publishedAt: 2020-11-21 16:11:00 +0000, content: nil)
> article: Article(source: __lldb_expr_111.Source(id: Optional("usa-today"), name: "USA Today"), author: Optional("Joel Shannon, Grace Hauck"), title: "Coronavirus updates: Donald Trump Jr. tests positive; model estimates 471k US deaths by March; Cuomo to receive International Emmy - USA TODAY", articleDescription: Optional("Donald Trump Jr. tests positive for the coronavirus. Model predicts more deaths. Thanksgiving during a pandemic happened before. Latest COVID news."), url: https://www.usatoday.com/story/news/health/2020/11/21/covid-news-donald-trump-jr-positive-thanksgiving-travel-not-advised/6367181002/, urlToImage: https://www.gannett-cdn.com/presto/2020/11/21/NSTT/caa3ba8a-8e3c-4b49-82e2-2810caf33d05-Testing3.jpg?crop=1574,886,x0,y80&width=1600&height=800&fit=bounds, publishedAt: 2020-11-21 15:56:15 +0000, content: Optional("A coronavirus vaccine might not be widely available until several months into 2021.\r\nUSA TODAY\r\nThe U.S reported a record high of more than 195,000 new daily cases of COVID-19 Friday, the same week t… [+11662 chars]"))
> article: Article(source: __lldb_expr_111.Source(id: nil, name: "CBS Sports"), author: Optional(""), title: "Clemson vs. Florida State game postponed hours before kickoff as teams disagreed about whether to play - CBS Sports", articleDescription: Optional("A Clemson player's late positive test for COVID-19 is the reason for the abrupt postponement"), url: https://www.cbssports.com/college-football/news/clemson-vs-florida-state-game-postponed-hours-before-kickoff-as-teams-disagreed-about-whether-to-play/, urlToImage: https://sportshub.cbsistatic.com/i/r/2019/01/31/3cfd9702-8ef4-4f0d-9cc6-2601f4b3ad9c/thumbnail/1200x675/d00f9bb392291c844de43984526b773e/clemson.jpg, publishedAt: 2020-11-21 15:28:00 +0000, content: Optional("No. 4 Clemson and Florida State were set to kick off at noon ET in Tallahassee, Florida, a game that would have marked Tigers quarterback Trevor Lawrence's return to action following a positive COVID… [+3139 chars]")) ......

Comment: Could you also explain why you use enum coding keys in model? What exactly is it used for?

Comment: Just to avoid creating a property description in your structure. You might want in the future conform your structure to [CustomStringConvertible](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/customstringconvertible)

Answer (score 0):

> articles - description
> "Expected String value but found null instead."

Change

```
let description: String
```

to

```
let description: String?
```

Comment: For some reason if I make it optional then my "author" becomes nil, and if I make my "author" nil then my "urlToImage" becomes nil. I need that data, what can I do?

Answer (score 0):

It says there is no value at the first value, can you post the json response what you're getting as that would be useful. Another possibility could be that the json response is in a different order than what you are decoding.

You could just change description to an optional as that would get rid of the problem but then you wouldn't have a description so it doesn't fully solve the problem

```
let description: String?
```

Comment: Yes, making my description an optional does not help as I need it, also for some reason if I make it optional then my author becomes nil. Also, how do I get json response?